# Partial specialization for pointer as function return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a template wrapper function that returns a value like this:

```
template<class T>
T foo(Bar& bar, const char* key) {
    return bar.value<T>(key);
}
```

But I want it to handle pointer types a bit different, like this:

```
template<class T>
T foo(Bar& bar, const char* key) {
    return (T)bar.value<void*>(key);
}
```

So that I can do:

```
int x = foo<int>(bar, "x");
Baz* b = foo<Baz*>(bar, "b");
```

Writing it like above obviously gives me an error because of multiple definitions. Is there any other way to do this? I would prefer do not add a cast to each function that uses a pointer.

I've tried the following:

```
template<class T>
T foo(Bar& bar, const char* key) {
    if(std::is_pointer<T>::value)
        return (T)bar.value<void*>(key);
    else
        return bar.value<T>(key);
}
```

But that doesn't work either because there are QVariants involved and they produce an error by just instantiating one of its template functions with an unknown pointer type (the `bar.value<T>`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use tag dispatching to delegate the calls to helper functions that do different things based on whether `T` is a pointer type or not.

```
namespace detail
{
template<class T>
T foo(Bar& bar, const char* key, std::false_type /*not is_pointer*/) {
    return bar.value<T>(key);
}

template<class T>
T foo(Bar& bar, const char* key, std::true_type /*is_pointer*/) {
    return (T)bar.value<void*>(key);
}
}

template<class T>
T foo(Bar& bar, const char* key) {
    return detail::foo<T>(bar, key, std::is_pointer<T>{});
}
```

Comment: Well, that's also always a perennial favorite. +1

Comment: Maybe put the tag dispatch overloads into `namespace details`, so if your IDE does overload auto completion, they don't show up.

Answer (score 8):

Partial specialization for functions is not part of the language.

You could for example:

1. Delegate to some class template. Class templates can be partially specialized.
2. Use SFINAE.

   ```
   template<class T>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type
   foo(Bar& bar, const char* key) {return (T)bar.value<void*>(key);}

   template<class T>
   typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type
   foo(Bar& bar, const char* key) {return bar.value<T>(key);}
   ```

Comment: I did not know about `std::enable_if`, thanks for teaching me something new. I would like to mark your post as answer as well, but I went with @Praetorian's post.